# CodeIgniter form validation rule won't run if string is empty

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I have a custom rule, `regex[table_name.column_name.post_value]`, which I am using in the following manner:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
  'postal_code',
  'Postal code',
  'regex[countries.postal_code_regex.country_code]'
);
```

And here is my custom rule's function in *MY_Form_validation.php*:

```
public function regex($str, $field){
    list($table, $col, $post_val)=explode('.', $field);
    // Grab the regex
    $regex = $this->CI  ->db
                        ->limit(1)
                        ->select($col)
                        ->where($post_val, $_POST[$post_val])
                        ->get($table)
                        ->row($col);

    return preg_match('/'.$regex.'/', $str) === 1;
}
```

How do I get CodeIgniter to run this rule if the user sends an empty string?

**Note:** I cannot use the `required` rule as it depends on whether the database has the regex or not.

Comment: I don't get it: do you want the empty string to pass validation or fail?

Comment: use `required` in third parameter of `set_rules`

Comment: @raheelshan Please see my comment at the end.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I want to pass the empty string, check the database, and if the database has a regex, then fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with this rather ugly solution to my own question:

```
if( isset($_POST['country_code']) && $_POST['postal_code'] == NULL){
  $_POST['postal_code'] = ' ';
}
```

I then added the `trim` rule to ensure it does not store the space in the database.

Of course, if anyone can think of a better solution, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
public function regex($str, $field){
    list($table, $col, $post_val)=explode('.', $field);
    // Grab the regex
    $regex = $this->CI  ->db
                        ->limit(1)
                        ->select($col)
                        ->where($post_val, $_POST[$post_val])
                        ->get($table)
                        ->row($col);

    if(trim($str) === "")
    $str = 1;
    return preg_match('/'.$regex.'/', $str) === 1;
}
```

Comment: Won't work I'm pretty sure, I don't think empty values are validated at all.

Comment: Wesley is correct - I don't need to modify the rule's function. I need to run the rule even if the string is empty.